# Expansion of fibonacci generating function

Tags: generating-functions

First: I will be appreciated if you do the the expansion of $$ \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$$
Second: I've seen in some textbook(generatingfunctionology) in a phase of exapnsion it told: $$\frac{1}{1-xr_+}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j+r^j$$ I was confused when I saw the following in wikipedia: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (rx)^n=\frac{1}{1-xr}$$
(For your information$$ r_+=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$) 
Now I don't know how those two sum are equal and how do thay Measured the first sum .

Comment: Welcome to the community! It seems that in the textbook the sign is misprinted as $+$ and it should be $x^j × r^j$

Comment: Thanks.which one of them?

Comment: Thanks again but what is the proof of $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (rx)^n =\frac{1}{1-xr}$$

Comment: @Abbas The proof of that is the Geometric Series. Start googling it, and read some wikipedia notes.

Comment: Thank you for answering